# convert an integer into 2 bytes in python

Tags: python, struct

Hey I have this code where I want to represent 1 as two bytes but when I access it back I am getting (1,) I do not want the comma and want to equate it like y==1

```
var = struct.pack(' h ', 1)
x = calcsize('h')
print(x)
y=struct.unpack('h', var)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the first value from the tuple like below,

```py
y = struct.unpack('h', var)[0]
```

or you can get the first value like below,

```py
y, *_ = struct.unpack('h', var)
```

or

```py
y, = struct.unpack('h', var)
```

Answer (score 1):

`struct.unpack` *always* returns a tuple regardless of the number of elements. The easiest fix is to assign y like this:

```
y, = struct.unpack('h', var) # notice the comma
```

This will unpack the tuple into a single value